# Managing data from CSV import using python

Tags: python, list, csv, pythonanywhere, csv-import

I am running into some hurdles with a csv that I am trying to manage. My goal is to open a csv file that is stored on my pythonanwywhere account that consists of two columns (ids and volume) and split those columns into two lists for downstream manipulation and ultimately output two new csv files.

I keep running into issues splitting the imported list in general. If I try to create a new list I get an index error: list out of range. There are only two columns in the csv so I thought the index should simply be 0 and 1.

I have tried a variety of ways to handle this data but keep getting tripped up. This is the current code I'm working with:

```
import csv
ids =[]
volume =[]

with open('TestImportCSV.csv', newline='') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = '\t')
#reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
        for row in reader:
            print(row[0])
```

If I just print the csv for row it looks like this:

```
['SampleID, Volumes']
['PD0014-8258', '319']
['PD0014-8259', '313']
['PD0014-8117', '513']
['PD0014-8613', '373']
['PD0014-8719', '221']
```

Whereas printing the index of row[0] results in a list index out of range error and outputs:

```
SampleID, Volumes
PD0014-8258
PD0014-8259
PD0014-8117
PD0014-8613
PD0014-8719
```

I feel like there is probably a fairly straightforward solution to this but there must be something I'm overlooking.

****EDIT****
Adding samples of input file formatting below.

Excel CSV:
"Column1" "Column2"

```
SampleID    Volumes
PD0014-8258 319
PD0017-8259 313
PD0014-8117 513
```

Uploaded to pythonanywhere:

```
1 SampleID Volumes
2 PD0014-8258 319
3 PD0014-8259 313
4 PD0014-8117 513
```

Downloaded file from pythonanywhere, opened with notepad:

```
SampleID, Volumes
"PD0014-8258    319",
"PD0014-8259    313",
"PD0014-8117    513",
```

Comment: You probably have an empty line in the file.

Comment: You really should show the first lines of the file and the last ones. And say whether  printing `row[0]` actually printed all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine.

Your input file has a comma in the header instead of a tab.

Please include the TestImportCSV.csv file to confirm this.

Your output looks impossible:
It looks like your header doesn't have the correct delimiter. Look closely: it's missing the closing quote after SampleID and the openning quote before Volumes.

check your code with a cleaned up input file.

Comment: That's more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Guy, your comment is more of a comment then an answer. :-)

Comment: Guy, I edited my answer to be an actual answer: "Your code is fine." In other news, the original question has exactly zero question marks. :-)

Comment: Adding *Your code is fine* doesn't make it an answer, just more comment. And although the delimiter the OP uses is *probably* wrong, the result would have been wrong output, not an exception.

Comment: The question is how to do it. He's doing it right, so "your code is fine" is the right answer. I'm not guessing. I ran the code. I get the same result that he does with a comma in the header.

Comment: Poleguy, I'm not sure how to go about uploading my csv to SO. It's not possible, correct? The .csv file I am using just contains sampleid as the header for one column and volumes as the header in the adjacent column. When I run the code it prints with a ',' and '\t'.

Comment: Right, you can't "upload" the file. But since a .csv file is a text file, just paste a few lines of the .csv file in your question. If you open your csv file in a text editor and change it so that it is consistently using either tabs or commas, and not a mix, does your code suddenly work correctly?

Comment: @ThomasBever I'm happy to keep helping, but if you feel my post answered the question, can you mark it as accepted? I'm trying to break 200 points.

Comment: @poleguy I added some sample formatting of how my data looks from original Excel CSV, uploaded to pythonanywhere, and saved f/m pythonanywherre and opened with notepad. It looks like the formatting is being changed as its passed along. Any thoughts or comments about that?

Comment: @poleguy And on that note...is it possible to just open a local csv on the desktop from pythonanywhere. I haven't found anything in the help forums that explicitly address that topic.

Comment: @Thomas Bever csv files are not specifically excel files. Just open the original in a text editor, like notepad: Right click, open as... I don't know what pythonanywhere is. I don't use excel. Csv means comma separated values. First edit your csv by hand in notepad until it works. Then let's talk.

Comment: @poleguy Thanks for the info. Pythonanywhere is a web based utility that allows you to run Python. Did you happen to see my edit to the original post? I tried to convey the formatting. It looks like the formatting changes when I upload my csv to the website. I'm wondering if that is my issue. I'm not able to open the file locally, i.e. from notepad using pythonanywhere. I haven't had the chance to do anymore work with it the last few days as we are nearing lock-down =|. Hopefully  I'll have time to check it out later today or tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: I did see your edit. That's a very different question than the first one you asked. It's not a stackoverflow question at all. I think it might be a question for pythonanywhere.com support? You should install python locally, and see that my answer of your original question is correct. I'd appreciate you accepting my answer as correct. Good luck. (BTW: Locally means open it from your hard drive, not anything to do with pythonanywhere. If you can't open a text file on your own hard drive, you need some more training than I'm willing to provide for free. Maybe find some video tutorials or mentor?)